# manually scale color of a factor in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, geom-point, scale-color-manual

Let's say i have a data frame like this

```
id password   year     length    Something
1 1234567      2001     7         good
2 pass4      2001       5         bad
3 angel3     2003       6         bad
4 pizza      2004       5         ok
```

im trying to get a code that would create a geom_point with 3 variable but i only want to highlight a single level of the factor ''Something'' . And i dont want any of the other levels of the factor Something(like good or bad) to colored. Or at least they can stay black.

im was thinking maybe something like this :

```
graph <- dat %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x=(year), y=length, color=Something$ok)+
      geom_point()
```

but i can't use $ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can color just one point by setting all points to one color and changing the color of the point you want to change. To do this you can use `scale_color_manual`

Data:

```
dat <- structure(list(id = 1:4, password = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L
), .Label = c("1234567", "angel3", "pass4", "pizza"), class = "factor"), 
    year = c(2001L, 2001L, 2003L, 2004L), length = c(7L, 5L, 
    6L, 5L), Something = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("bad", 
    "good", "ok"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Plot:

```
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=(year), y=length, color = Something == "ok"))+
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "orange"))
```

[image: example]